# symfony2 on nginx 500 internal server error

Tags: symfony, nginx

I am new to symfony. I am trying to setup symfony2 on ubuntu server with nginx. but it shows 500 internal server error. I have this server running some laravel projects as well and its find

Anyone can help what the problem is?

my nginx configuration is :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/ubuntu/test-symfony/web;
    index app.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name symfony.jonesjapriady.com  http://symfony.jonesjapriady.com;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony2.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony2.access.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|app_test.php|app)\.php(/|$) {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do your logs say ?

Comment: @TomToms it says 12089 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 27.32.198.16, server: symfony.jonesjapriady.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "symfony.jonesjapriady.com". I don't get why it is looking for index.php while my conf is to app.php and i have restart nginx.